# How to Autofill Textboxes on a Form using a Loop?

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have a table that has a list of totals im trying to display on a form, I have 10 totals I need to get from the totals table and display in 10 textboxes on the form.

The 10 textboxes are `"A1, A2, A3..."` and its using `DLookup` to find the ID field number.

It seems like its a syntax issue with `Me.TEXTX & X1.Value` though I'm not sure how else I can type it.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

```vb
Private Sub UPDATETOTALS()
    Dim FORMX As String
    FORMX = "GRID"

    Dim TEXTX As String
    TEXTX = "A"

    Dim TABLENAMEx As String, FINDFIELDx As String, GETFIELDx As String
    TABLENAMEx = "GRID_TOTALS"
    FINDFIELDx = "[ID]="
    GETFIELDx = "TODAY"

    Dim X1 As Integer
    For X1 = 1 To 10
        Me.TEXTX & X1.Value = DLookup(GETFIELDx, TABLENAMEx, FINDFIELDx & X1)
    Next X1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access an object reference directly using a concatenated string, as such reference is not of string data type.

Instead, you will need to access the object from the relevant collection (in this case, the `Controls` collection), by supplying the name of the object (as a string) to the `Item` method of that collection.

Since the `Item` method is the default method for a collection, the item name can immediately follow the collection as an argument.

**For example:**

```vb
For X1 = 1 To 10
    Me.Controls(TEXTX & X1).Value = DLookup(GETFIELDx, TABLENAMEx, FINDFIELDx & X1)
Next X1
```